# Проблема с передачей аргументов функции

Tags: javascript, html, css, алгоритм, функции

Не могу понять почему js сопротивляется и не хочет подставлять переданные аргументы в функцию и выдает ошибку: pipe.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: action is not a function
Если один аргумент, то: pipe.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: action is not a function
Если несколько(как в примере), то: undefinded

Объясните пожалуйста, буду очень признателен.

```js
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
const addOne = x => x + 1;
const square = x => x * x;


function fn(...action) {
  return (...args) => {
    if (action.length > 1) {
      return action.forEach(item => {
        item(...args);
      });
    } else {
      action(...args);
    }
  }
}

console.log(fn(multiply, addOne, square)(3, 4));
```

Comment: у Array​.prototype​.for​Each() возвращаемое значение undefined

Comment: в приведенном сниппете проблема не воспроизводится

Comment: rest parameters - это **всегда** массив. Поэтому если передали один аргумент, надо его и вызывать `action[0](...args)`

Comment: кстати, а какой результат ты ожидал получить конкретно в данном случае?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите получить массив на выходе, то используйте метод Array.prototype.map(), так как Array.prototype.forEach() всегда возвращает undefined.

Будьте бдительны args - массив

```js
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
const addOne = x => x + 1;
const square = x => x * x;


function fn(...action) {
  return (args) => {
    if (action.length > 1) {
      return action.map(item => {
        return item(...args);
      });
    } else {
      return action[0](...args); // либо так либо вообще без этой части
    }
  }
}

console.log(fn(multiply, addOne, square)([3, 4]));
console.log(fn(multiply)([3, 4]));
```

Можно вторую часть опустить.

```js
    const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
    const addOne = x => x + 1;
    const square = x => x * x;


    function fn(...action) {
      return (args) => {
          return action.map(item => {
            return item(...args);
          });
      }
    }

    console.log(fn(multiply, addOne, square)([3, 4]));
    console.log(fn(multiply)([3, 4]));
```

Comment: А если так, то тоже не получаетсяfunction                                                                        
fn(...action) {
  return (...args) => {
    if (action.length > 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < action.length; i++) {
        action[i](...args);
      }
    } else {
      action(...args);
    }
  }
}

console.log(fn(multiply, addOne, square)(3, 4));

Comment: @Proger0912, что не получается-то? :-) ты же ничего не возвращаешь в своем коде, а в консоль выводишь то, что твоя `fn` возвращает, то есть _ничего_, поэтому и видишь `undefined`

Comment: Благодарю, разобрался

Comment: `...` перед `args` забыл в объявлении. А, ты зачем-то поменял формат аргумента, но зачем?